# Compass spriting with Assetic on Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, sass

It's my first time using Symfony so I don't know if I'm messing everything up or what but I can't seem to get compass spriting working on my project apparently.

This is what I have on my scss files:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

And I don't see any errors when compiling de sass but the icons are nowhere to be found and the css generated is something like:

```
 .icons-sprite, .icons-icon01, .icons-icon02 {
     background: url("/images/icons-sf92f9256db.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
```

On my config.yml file I have this:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass: ~
        compass: 
            bin: '/usr/bin/compass'
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
            http_path: /
            images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Es/DolceVitaBundle/Resources/assets/images
            generated_images_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images
            http_generated_images_path: /images

parameters:
    assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Es/DolceVitaBundle/Resources/assets/images
    assetic.filter.compass.http_path:  /images
```

And my icons folder (with the original png files that I want to use for the sprite) is in /Myprojectfolder/src/src/Es/DolceVitaBundle/Resources/assets/images

The folder in /Myprojectfolder/src/web/images is empty

EDIT:

More info: I did app/console assetic:dump --watch and the css files were generated fine

And my styleshhets are added like this:

```
{% stylesheets output='css/*.css' filter="compass" 
    "@EsDolceVitaBundle/Resources/assets/scss/style.scss"
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: did you run `app/console assets:install` or `app/console assetic:dump` ? Where and how do you create the assetic package ? inside a twig file with a `{% stylesheets %}` tag or in your config under `assetic.assets`?

Comment: Edited with that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently something was off, maybe the cache, but the rest of my config was ok. I did the rest of my css and commented the icons part and after working for a day I uncommented to look at the issue again and the sprite showed up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add to your parameters.yml:

```
assetic.filter.compass.generated_images_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images
```